# Error Nodejs Geocode with OpenStreetMap/Nominatim

Tags: node.js, openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

I have a website which needs to obtain the Latitude and Longitude which correspond to an address of a user, and then entered the information in my database (mongodb).

Google/Bing/Yahoo are too expensive for us so we went with OpenStreetMap/Nominatim.

My code is the folowing :

```
const options = {
  provider: 'openstreetmap',
};

const geoCoder = NodeGeocoder(options); 



geoCoder
          .geocode({
            city: Adresse_fixe_ville,
            zipcode: Adresse_fixe_postal,
          })
          .then(async (res) => {
            const Latitude = res[0].latitude;
            const Longitude = res[0].longitude;

            //CREATE A STUDENT WHITH THE INFO + LAT AND LONG
            student = new Student({
              Civilite,
              Nom_patronymique,
              Prenom,
              Date_naissance,
              No_etudiant,
              Libelle_nationalite,
              Telephone_portable,
              Mailum,
              Adresse_fixe_postal,
              Adresse_fixe_ville,
              Libelle_etape,
              Latitude,
              Longitude,
            });
            //VERIFICATION of undefined .....
            ) {
              //SAVE THE STUDEN IN THE DATABASE
              await student.save();
            } else {
              //Res error .....
            }
          })
```

Everything is working well when i deal with small data volume . (for less than 40 users) But when i whant to upload my 1300 users , it's blocked during the process of the 42 user. In fact i firstly have the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
[0]     at Geocoder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\justi\Documents\GitHub\carpoolingApplication\routes\api\students.js:105:37)
[0]     at Geocoder.tryCatcher (C:\Users\justi\Documents\GitHub\carpoolingApplication\node_modules\node-geocoder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
```

.

And then i have this error message for all the users when i try to decode the adress and save i data base :

```
HttpError: request to http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?addressdetails=1&city=MONT-DE-MARSAN&zipcode=40000&format=json failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 130.117.76.9:80
[0]     at C:\Users\justi\Documents\GitHub\carpoolingApplication\node_modules\node-geocoder\lib\httpadapter\fetchadapter.js:47:15
[0]     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\justi\Documents\GitHub\carpoolingApplication\node_modules\node-geocoder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
[0]     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\justi\Documents\GitHub\carpoolingApplication\node_modules\node-geocoder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
[0]     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\justi\Documents\GitHub\carpoolingApplication\node_modules\node-geocoder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
[0]     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\justi\Documents\GitHub\carpoolingApplication\node_modules\node-geocoder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
[0]     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\justi\Documents\GitHub\carpoolingApplication\node_modules\node-geocoder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:725:18)
[0]     at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\justi\Documents\GitHub\carpoolingApplication\node_modules\node-geocoder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
[0]     at _drainQueue (C:\Users\justi\Documents\GitHub\carpoolingApplication\node_modules\node-geocoder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
[0]     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\justi\Documents\GitHub\carpoolingApplication\node_modules\node-geocoder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
[0]     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\justi\Documents\GitHub\carpoolingApplication\node_modules\node-geocoder\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
[0]     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21) {
[0]   name: 'HttpError',
[0]   message: 'request to http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?addressdetails=1&city=MONT-DE-MARSAN&zipcode=40000&format=json failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 130.117.76.9:80',
[0]   code: 'ETIMEDOUT'
[0] }
```

I have made a lot of research about this problem but can't find a solution or an alternative. Im aware about the nominatim usage policy (https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/?fbclid=IwAR1amydpXK6TXhWk_DPKwkeRGwFz4Z6OyQpp6DYcpklEZx_6m1e9JpkgvMQ) . And i guess i made too many request. But how can i resolve this problem ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Respect the [usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim). Reduce your number of requests per second or [switch to a commercial Nominatim instance or install your own Nominatim instance](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers).

Comment: It seems like you hit the rate limit of open street map. There is perhaps somewhere at the 42nd users in your data.

Comment: Yes i try to respect the usage policy, but do you know how can i reduce the number of requests per second ? Becaus i try with some time sleep but it's doewn't work ...

Comment: I just run into the same problem. Were you able to fix this @JustineFOULQUIER ?

Comment: Yes, it's because I've made too many requests and I don't respect the one request per second rule. So I added a wait(1second) between each request, it made my program much longer but it works!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the query wrong.

For 'openstreetmap' you can only use query.

```
let results: any = await geocoder.geocode(query);
```